# C++: Correct implementation for passing a std::string to a C function that wants to change the string?

Tags: c++, char, stdstring

I have a function in a third-party library written in C: `char* fix_filename_slashes(char* path)`. This function expects a mutable C-string passed to it so it can change all the slashes in the path to the correct use based on the operating system. All the strings I'm using in my Facade are declared as `std::string`s. I attempted to simply use `foo.c_str()` as every other function that expects a C string doesn't change it and expects a `const char *`, but this function causes an error: `Error: Argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"`

Is the result I came up with:

```
char* tempf = const_cast<char*>(filename.c_str());
filename = std::string(fix_filename_slashes(tempf));
tempf = NULL;
```

considered "correct" or are there other (more correct?) ways to accomplish the task?

**EDIT**

Whups. Apparently the function returns a COPY of the string. Still there are some nice answers already given.

Comment: it has undefined behavior written all over it

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: Could you explain the UB so I know what's wrong?

Comment: 21.3.6 ...    const charT* c_str() const;   .... "The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the array"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the string length does not change, you can use a pointer to the first character of the string. This is undefined behavior in the C++03 standard, but all known implementations work properly and it is explicitly allowed under the C++11 standard.

```
fix_filename_slashes(&filename[0]);
```

If the size of the string may change, you'll have to do a little more work.

```
filename.resize(max_size, 0);
append_filename_suffix(&filename[0]);
filename.resize(strlen(filename.c_str()));
```

Comment: whats the fix in the standard?

Comment: After some testing I've determined the function does not change the length. So yeah, see edit. Kinda stupid to expect a non-const member if a copy is returned. Nothing I can do about it though.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into a null-terminated sequence of characters stored in a `std::vector`:

```
template <typename Character>
std::vector<Character> to_vector(std::basic_string<Character> const& s)
{
    std::vector<Character> v;
    v.reserve(s.size() + 1);
    v.insert(v.end(), s.begin(), s.end());
    v.push_back(0);
    return v;
}
```

Usage example:

```
std::string filename = get_filename();
std::vector<char> filename_cstr = to_vector(filename);
filename = std::string(fix_filename_slashes(&filename_cstr[0]));
```

Comment: Can you use the `iterator, iterator` constructor of vector instead of the insert, still doing the final `push_back`?

Comment: it would have been shorter to write `vector<char> v(filename.begin(), filename.end());` to copy string to vector, followed by `push_back(0);`

Comment: @Mark, @Gene:  Yes, but this way you are guaranteed that only one allocation takes place (the allocation performed by `reserve`).  If you use the range constructor you may end up with two allocations (one by the range constructor, one by `push_back`).

Comment: @Mark yes you can, and you might want to do `v.push_back('\0');` as well. The template is optional depending but it is nice to have it work for `char, `unsigned char`, `wchar_t`, etc. You could then pass `v.data()` into the C function.

Comment: Waayyy too difficult, just write `std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end()); v.push_back(0);`

Comment: @Kerrek:  To copy and paste what I said _two comments above yours,_ "this way you are guaranteed that only one allocation takes place...if you use the range constructor you may end up with two allocations."  @AJG85:  `\0'` might be preferable to some, but then you end up having to widen the character correctly for other character types if the function is to be kept generic.  It shouldn't really matter since the null terminator is guaranteed to be represented by all-bits zero.

Comment: @James: Oops, my bad on missing that comment. However, if you use random access iterators to initialize a vector, there's a very good chance that you'll only incur one allocation.

Comment: @Kerrek:  Yes:  it is guaranteed that the initialization `std::vector<Character> v(s.begin(), s.end());` will only perform a single allocation.  However, it may very well allocate only `std::distance(s.begin(), s.end())` elements in the container, which would cause the `v.push_back(0)` to reallocate the underlying sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to all the trouble you could just comply with the requirements of the C function and copy your string to a char array then after the function create a string from the char array or force a copy assignment on your original string.

```
    char* temp = new char[str.size() + 1]
    // Force a copy of the result into another string
    str = (const char*)fix_filename_slashes(strncpy(temp, str.c_str(), str.size() + 1));
    delete [] temp;
```

Comment: `delete [] temp;` and after calling `strncpy` with `str.size()`, `temp` is not null terminated. Also memory leak if `fix_filename_slashes` throws exception (probably not, but what if?); and why bother casting to `const char*`? (gosh, I'm picky)

Comment: Fixed the code, however C functions do not throw exceptions and I know that there should be a lot more checking going on, it was for illustration purposes only.

Comment: true about exceptions, that's why I said I was picky ;-)

Comment: There is still no reason to use manual memory management, though.  The use of `std::vector` is cleaner and less error-prone.

Comment: True, and your solution is elegant, but if there is going to be any error its in a function named fix_filename_slashes :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the `string` used a separate buffer to store the `c_str` string this wouldn't modify the original string.

Better is to create a `char` buffer on the stack or heap, copy the characters into it (null terminated), call the fix function, and then assign the buffer back into the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that takes a little setup, but works automatically after that. It relies on a temporary object, which takes a copy of the original string and copies the modified string back in the destructor. Obviously all this copying won't be too efficient, but in most cases the efficiency won't matter.

```
class mutable_string
{
public:
    mutable_string(std::string & str, int maxlen = 0) : m_str(str)
    {
        m_buffer.resize(max(maxlen, str.length()) + 1);
        memcpy(&m_buffer[0], str.c_str(), str.length()+1);
    }
    ~mutable_string()
    {
        m_str = m_buffer;
    }
    operator char* ()
    {
        return &m_buffer[0];
    }
private:
    std::string &     m_str;
    std::vector<char> m_buffer;
};

fix_filename_slashes(mutable_string(filename));
```